# Nice way to print_r arrays

Tags: array, formatting

So you know how Drupal has functions in modules like Devel that allow you to output arrays in a nice format like `dsm($array)` or `krumo($array)`... Does WordPress have an equivalent or a nice way of displaying `print_r($array)`?

Comment: what is wwrong with var_dump() or print_r() ? what exactly are you aiming for ? (i am sorry, I do not know druppal so well ..

Comment: krumo allows users to print arrays into a formatted list that expands on click. So instead of having <pre>-wrapped print_r output everywhere, you end up with some very nice dropdown lists instead. Much nicer to display!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created a Kint plugin that works really well. I also integrates with the Debug Bar plugin. You can download it at: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kint-debugger/

There are a few functions to help you out with WordPress specific globals:

- `dump_wp_query()`
- `dump_wp()`
- `dump_post()`

For printing arrays in a styled, collapsible format you would do the following.

```
$foo_bar = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => 'oof',
    'rab' => 'foo'
);
d($foo_bar); //Styled
s($foo_bar); //Un-styled
```

Comment: What a great idea, cheers.

Answer (score 7):

You can install and use [Krumo](http://kaloyan.info/krumo/) with WordPress (or any PHP app really). There's the [Hikari Krumo plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hikari-krumo/) that simplifies use, though check the comments there, there's an error that you'll need to manually fix to get it working with latest WP. There's also the WordPress [Debug Bar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) which you might find useful.

EDIT- Another option I've recently discovered, [Kint](http://raveren.github.io/kint/); screenshot:

[image: Kint screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

For this kind of stuff, I wrote [**REF**](https://github.com/digitalnature/php-ref) (requires PHP 5.3). Among many other features, it displays contents of DocBlock comments and linkifies PHP-internal classes, methods and functions (links point to the PHP manual). It also handles WordPress functions (links point to [queryposts.com](http://queryposts.com/)).

Here's the output of `$GLOBALS` at the `setup` stage of WordPress in HTML mode (`r($GLOBALS);` in functions.php):

[image]

Comment: +1 for DB user `root` and an empty password.

Comment: lol never thought WP would actually store that too :)

Comment: One Trick, the image went missing.

Comment: Seems to show up for me. I added a new one to reflect the last updates to this script

Comment: This is incredible!! SO needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you just wrap the `print_r()` in `<pre>` tags it will output beautifully. If you're looking for a bit better diagnostics than that, [black box](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/) and the debug bar posted by @Milo are my gotos.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use the plugin [Debug Objects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-objects/); list also scripts and styles.
The Plugin has many more options for dev and debugging, but also this feature.

Alternative is this source, you find informations and the post about this topic [here](http://wpengineer.com/2308/debug-enqueued-scripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/):

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'fb_urls_of_enqueued_stuff');
add_action('admin_footer', 'fb_urls_of_enqueued_stuff');
function fb_urls_of_enqueued_stuff( $handles = array() ) {
    global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;
    // scripts
    foreach ( $wp_scripts -> registered as $registered )
        $script_urls[ $registered -> handle ] = $registered -> src;
    // styles
    foreach ( $wp_styles -> registered as $registered )
        $style_urls[ $registered -> handle ] = $registered -> src;
    // if empty
    if ( empty( $handles ) ) {
        $handles = array_merge( $wp_scripts -> queue, $wp_styles -> queue );
        array_values( $handles );
    }
    // output of values
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $handles as $handle ) {
        if ( ! empty( $script_urls[ $handle ] ) )
            $output .= $script_urls[ $handle ] . '<br />';
        if ( ! empty( $style_urls[ $handle ] ) )
            $output .= $style_urls[ $handle ] . '<br />';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use xdebug?

Looks pretty neat to me, by default.

[image]

There is also Kint, http://code.google.com/p/kint/ but I found the dropdowns more confusing, then the full output of xdebug.

Comment: +1 And don't forget to configure it in your `php.ini` file to avoid those nasty `...` for nested stuff.